# DebugMode property in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a property called DebugMode in my settings file which is of type boolean. Quite useful when it comes to testing new features and taking control over the production version at the same time.

I was wondering if there is some built-in property called DebugMode which i can use to control which features get into production and which are just for testing?

Or maybe there are levels of debugging, like Warning, Message, Error, Critical Error or something like that?

Yes there is a class called

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger
```

But I am  not sure how to use it.

I will delete the question if it is too basic.

Comment: *"I will delete the question if it is too basic."* You should - You are asking about multiple things at once. If you want to differentiate between release and debug builds, use the build configurations and a couple of pre-processor directives.

Comment: Aham, so I should  learn about build configs a bit more.

Comment: Yes, keep in mind however, that those kind of settings can't be changed during runtime - which is actually good because all the ifs don't get compiled and your code gets a tiny bit faster and smaller.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Ok. So even if I use build configurations, how am I going to disable features which are in development when I build for release? I think again it all goes down to a property in a *.settings file or in the project configuration file. Not sure. Is there a way to check if I build for release or for debug with code?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Aham I see. If in Debug configuration, #if DEBUG #endif will execute what is in it and if in Release build configuration it will not execute what is in the pre-processor directive. Neat! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is certainly, You can use preprocessor directives [`#if DEBUG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) like

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit of information about build configurations - doesn't sound like OP knows how to define or use pre-processor directives.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, that's why linked the language reference page